# When ToastBar messages are manually cleared, components below them are clicked as well... Any suggestions?

Tags: components, codenameone, transparency

I am testing a mobile app I have built and noticed that when I manually clear a `ToastBar` message through the touch interface, if there is a `Component` beneath it, such as a `Button`, it is clicked as well.

I know that in Android native development, it is possible to mark a `Component` in a way that does not allow this to happen. Does anyone know if there is such a method or "attribute" in Codename One too?

Comment: You can use setEnabled(false) but that's probably not a good idea. Do you mean when you touch the toastbar or when you invoke `clear()` in code? I see a potential problem in our code. We'll push an improvement this Friday that might resolve this.

Comment: Dear @ShaiAlmog, I edited the question to better reflect the circumstances. I provide more context here.

A ToastBar message pops for whatever reason. I "touch" on it, trying to clear it manually. Beneath it, there is e.g., an exit `Button`. The message is cleared, and the app exits too...

In Android, there is a way to set any `Component` as non "transparent", not allowing other `Components` beneath it to activate potential `ActionListener`s, which by the way is a security risk as well.

Imagine someone purposely placing a rogue `Component` under a legit one.

Comment: We have several ways of blocking an input to a component (including setEnabled). I think the fix I made might solve this issue though. Please try a build after this Friday to see if the issue was resolved.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I assume you disable a `Component` when overlapped by another? I have taken measures to address the issue differently. I will take the chance at a later time to test the new feature. Thank you very much for the quick correspondence.

Comment: No. I consume the event

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Ok, I assume you `consume` the event of the `Component` beneath or `consume` it in general so as not to trigger other than the intended action?

Comment: We're open source, you can just look at the commit history and see ;-) https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/f43442e28e320ffc9b6cf9e41f0ffef7691df208#diff-d9fe70fd6c2b62298dab4ab9911aebba47cca5f76811eefb2e95548b536ca23f

Comment: Forgot that @ShaiAlmog. Thank you for reminding it to me.